# Migrate database from Dspace 4 to Dspace 6

Tags: flyway, dspace

I am trying to migrate a database from DSpace 4 to DSpace 6.
I exported the DSpace 4 database and imported it locally in my DSpace 6.3 installation.
The database information is as follows

[database information](https://pastebin.com/raw/VmEd9xZn)

Then I do:

```
/dspace/bin/dspace database repair
/dspace/bin/dspace database migrate

Database URL: jdbc:postgresql://172.18.0.2:5432/dspace
Migrating database to latest version AND running previously "Ignored" migrations... (Check logs for details)
Migration exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Flyway migration error occurred
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.updateDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:673)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.main(DatabaseUtils.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.runOneCommand(ScriptLauncher.java:229)
    at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:81)
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 4.1
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1008)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:72)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:921)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:917)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1373)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:917)
    at org.dspace.storage.rdbms.DatabaseUtils.updateDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:662)
    ... 7 more
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the solution but maybe a clue: the "Upgrade to Dspace Vlir schema" entry in your database link looks strange to me. I searched for it and couldn't find any references to this in the standard DSpace documentation. Could this be some kind of customization? Does "Vlir" say anything in the context of your repository?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this might help you, it seems to be a problem with foreign key naming.
http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/Flyway-Migration-Error-td4677061.html